# Change XamGrid column header dynamically

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I am having user group returning from wcf service and using view model binding it to xamgrid in view, Since grid is having auto generate column is true, grid column headers same as propertyname(without space).

I want to change the column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it. If you still want to do auto generate columns true then you can subscribe to AutoGeneratingColumn event in the grid and listen to each column and set the column header to the name you want. The other option not sure it will work in your case, is in the model you can decorate each member using component model annotation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490428(v=vs.95).aspx or [Using DataAnnotations (DisplayColumn) in WCF RIA Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343676/using-dataannotations-displaycolumn-in-wcf-ria-services)

Comment: Thanks, listening to each column works even with auto generated columns is true.

Comment: yes it does, so you can intercept the event and add the space for each words. Do you still have problem implementing it?

Comment: If and only if you think my answer solved your problem, please do mark that as answer. It helps others as well.